# Most elegant way to initialise a string with a single character from another string

Tags: c++, string, char

Is there a more elegant way to initialise the second string with a single char from the first string? Eg. without resorting to the string ( size_t n, char c ) constructor?

```
string first = "foobar";
string second(string(1, first[0]));
```

Comment: Why are you even constructing twice? Leave the `string(...)` part out in the second string.

Comment: What is inelegant about using that constructor?

Comment: Since you already have `(1, first[0])` as arguments of a constructor, why don't you just use it to construct `second`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The constructor you mention *is* the way to create a string from one character, so there won't be a significantly more elegant way. However, there's no need to create and copy/move a temporary:

```
string second(1, first[0]);
```

Alternatively, you could construct from a substring of `first`:

```
string second(first, 0, 1);
```

In C++11, you can use an initialiser list:

```
string second {first[0]};
```

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
string ( );
string ( const string& str );
string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos );
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
string ( const char * s );
string ( size_t n, char c ); //<<--- this
```

i.e.

```
string second(1, first[0]);
```

Note that the above are your only options for initialization.

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvoting; +1 for compensation.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume it's because the question says "without resorting to the string ( size_t n, char c ) constructor?"

Comment: @JoeGauterin ah, ok. Then no :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but those aren't the only options. There's also an iterator range, and in C++11 an initialiser list.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you:

```
string first = "foobar";
string second;
second = first[0];
```

Comment: Much better than `string second(1, first[0]);`

Comment: Except it does not compile, since there is no `string(char c)` constructor: http://ideone.com/KyOFg.

Comment: @omercan1993 for initialization, it's not `operator =` that is used, but the constructor. You're still wrong.

Comment: @omercan1993: Right, but you need a constructed string for that. Initializing an object with `=` does not call the assignment operator.

Comment: I guess you can just change it to `string second; second = first[0];`

Comment: It's true... my failure... I just edit it to the true version... but it is not elegant anymore :)