# converting char into string for stack<string>

Tags: c++, palindrome

I'm doing the whole palindrome program using stacks and queues for homework. Our professor made us write the stack and queue from scratch and specific to strings only. I am reading in text from a file and determining wether or not the sentence is a palindrome. I obviously need to push each character into the stack and queue, however, how can i push a character into a stack that accepts a string as parameter!?

```
//get data from txt file
void getData(Stack &myStack, Queue &myQueue)
{
ifstream infile;

string temp;
int i = 0;

infile.open("palindrome.txt");

if (!infile)
{
    cout << "The file failed to open." << endl;
    exit(-1);
}

while (getline(infile, temp))
{

    //remove spaces form sentences
    temp.erase(remove_if(temp.begin(), temp.end(), ::isspace),temp.end());

 //need to push each character into stack and queue here
 //there are 5 sentences total in the file to check


    i++;


 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474147/most-elegant-way-to-initialise-a-string-with-a-single-character-from-another-str

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a constructor taking (count, char), like this:

```
char ch = 'A';
std::string str(1, ch);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string